# MAC address table in Windows

Tags: windows, bridge

How can I see the MAC address table of a Windows network bridge?
Is it possible trough command line to find this information?

**EDIT**: I am interested to see the same table that it is possible to see in the managed switches (e.g. like the Cisco's `show mac-address-table` or Linux `brctl showmacs br0`)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Network Bridge functionality appears to be wholly implemented (at least in Windows 7) by the `bridge.sys` driver. Without access to the `bridge.sys` source code it's difficult to say anything with certainty, but some cursory sniffing around the binary doesn't show any exposed APIs that would be helpful in dumping the layer 2 adjacency table.

(This ASCII text string embedded in the binary is a nice touch, though: `Without specific written consent from Microsoft, it is illegal to reverse engineer, debug or change this binary.`)

I think you're out-of-luck, from a documented and supported command-line perspective. Searching Microsoft's website for any command-line (or otherwise) tools that deal with the network bridge (aside from the [paltry support in `netsh`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc754586(v=ws.10).aspx)) isn't turning up anything for me.

It's interesting to note that [the names of the registry parameters specified for the Windows CE network bridge driver](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee494722.aspx) are present in the Windows 7 `bridge.sys` driver. This tends to make me think that these registry settings would work (not that any of them are helpful to you).

Dumping Windows kernel pool allocations is above my pay grade, but I suspect that if you were to figure out what the `bridge.sys` pool tag was (I suspect it's `Brdg`) and dump any pool allocations it makes you'd find the adjacency table in one of those allocations. Making that into a useful tool is left as an exercise to the reader. (>smile<)

Answer (score 2):

on a windows system, you can run `arp -a` to display the arp table for each interface.. is that not what you are looking for?

Comment: arp only shows mac-addresses associated with IP-addresses. There can be a lot more going on than just IP traffic.

Comment: nmap sweep would show all mac addresses no? I believe there's a port to windows.

Comment: Tis true.. would only show IP related MAC-addresses.

Comment: `arp -a` shows the arp table. I have a windows bridge and I was interested to see the MAC/interface table (bridge table) as you can see in the managed switches.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Windows doesn't maintain a separate MAC address table, it resolves MAC addresses as needed for L3. I know that in Junos, if your device does not have a single interface configured for ethernet switching, then you only have an ARP table or perhaps look at the forwarding plane's tables.

Comment: Habe you checked what's available using netsh.exe?

Comment: First, the ARP table wouldn't even show MAC addresses associated with IP addresses unless the system had to associate them locally, which a bridge typically doesn't have to do. Second, Windows *has* to have a MAC address table independent of its L3 operation, otherwise it couldn't bridge Ethernet interfaces, and we know it can.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz - The confusion people seem to have between ARP tables and layer 2 adjacency tables has amazed me for a long time. Books and other resources referring to layer 2 adjacency tables as "ARP tables" hasn't helped matters. I've pretty much just given up trying to explain it to people.